# Pandoc docx to HTML include height and width on <img> tag

Tags: html, docx, pandoc

I'm converting Microsoft `.docx` files to HTML using [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/). Currently using the `--extract-media` option generates `<img>` tags of the form `<img src='pandoc.image.png'>` but it doesn't add the `height` and `width` attributes of the image to the `<img>` tag. **How do I get pandoc to add the height and width properties of the image as attributes to the `<img>` tag?**

I'm only able to use the command line to do the conversion, no scripting. The command I'm running is `pandoc --from docx --to html input.docx --extract-media=/tmp/pandoc`

Comment: Maybe ask the creator of that library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Pandoc <1.16 [doesn't support image sizes](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/261) in its internal AST. So this is currently not possible. But once the Docx Reader is adjusted as well, this will work.